# How to start the SetupWizard on an emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, custom-rom, setup-wizard

I am working on a custom SetupWizard for a Android ROM and would like to test it on a VD but even with cold boot the devices skips the SetupWizard. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am currently struggling with the same problem.